# .htaccess remove everything after last /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the url so that everything after last slash will be removed and there should be no redirect. 
For example

```
site.com/content/?abc=true 
site.com/product/?view=false
```

will changes to

```
site.com/content/
site.com/product/
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

At `.htaccess` file in main root ,Match against `query string` , in such this part `abc=true` of given URLs which after `?` then , if it is exist , remove it like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     /$1?  [L,R=301]
```

So , if the query string is only exist `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$` remove it , `/$1` match aginst request URI `^(.*)$` and `?` next to it means don't append query string  .

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it is not working, I want the rewrite to be generic so that I don't have to write rule for each page. I put this in my .htaccess file `RewriteEngine On`    -    
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc=true$`    -    
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/^([A-Z][0-9][a-z]-_)\w\d*$/$1?  [L,R=301]`

Comment: @MAY what i wrote is general and to match any query string, paste the uri that you tested with

Comment: @MAY before test , make sure that you clear browser cache , this is very important